# How to write in LaTeX a function that breaks at one point?

Tags: math-mode, function

I have to use this command in solving questions for an app. I am in my training  period and this was not the part of the tutorial.

My function is defined as follows: f(x) = x+3 if x<-2 and $f(x)= \sqrt{x+2}$ if x>-2.( I am seeing in the output of this body that $ sign $ is not working). Does this SE site doesn't recognize TeX?

I want to write f(x) as follows: f(x) = ( then writing a curly bracket( { ) )in which writing  x+ 3 if x<-2 on top and $f(x)= \sqrt {x+2}$ if x>-2 on bottom. This is the standard way how it is written in the books on Math.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: `\[ f(x0=\begin{cases} x+3 & x<-2 \\ \sqrt{x+2} & x>-2 \end{cases}\]`

Comment: TeX code is not passed to MathJax on this site, because we're interested in the source code and not in an approximate representation of the output thereof.

Comment: I recommend reading [The not so short introduction to LaTeX](https://texdoc.org/serve/lshort/0); you find the example on page 58. Other beginner's manuals are listed at [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/)

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much for the book!